# ¿Cómo colocar un filtro en un listado de Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

En mi sistema tengo varios listados a los que debo añadirles filtros. Estos filtros serán una lista desplegable.

A modo de ejemplo, tengo un listado de usuarios del sistema y un filtro por tipo de usuarios, con los siguientes valores: todos, administradores, usuarios; y dependiendo lo que se seleccione el listado debe actualizarse.

He visto un sin fin de vídeos en youtube y leído documentación y no me queda claro como hacer para lograr crear estos filtros a través de listas desplegables.

¿Podrías indicarme una fuente en donde se explique de forma sencilla como realizar esto en Laravel 5.5 o escribirme un pequeño ejemplo?

Comment: Puedes poner lo que haz intentado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer un form con método `GET` y dentro de él añadir los campos que necesites:

```
<form action="{{ route('listado') }}" method="GET">
   <select name="tipo_usuario">
      <option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>
      @foreach($tipos as $tipo)
         <option value="{{ $tipo->id }}">{{ $tipo->nombre }}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="otro_campo">
   {{-- Puedes añadir cuantos campos te sean necesarios --}}
   <button type="submit">Filtrar resultados</button>
</form>

<table>
   @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $usuario->nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ $usuario->apellido }}</td>
      {{--  Agrega las columnas que necesites... --}}
   </tr>
   @endforeach
</table>
```

En tu archivo de rutas (normalmente 'web.php`) tendrías que registrar la ruta con alias "listado":

```
Route::get('/lista-de-usuarios', 'UsuariosController@listado')->name('listado');
```

En tu controlador que, en este ejemplo, lo puse como `UsuariosController` (tu puedes poner el que quieras) debes de agregar el método `listado`:

```
//Importas tus modelos al principio del archivo, suponiendo que los creas en la ruta por defecto de Laravel:

use App\{
   Usuario,
   TipoUsuario
};

public function listado(Request $request){
    //Inicializas el query:
    $usuarios = Usuario::query();

    //Obtienes los valores de tu request:
    $tipo_usuario = $request->tipo_usuario;
    $otro_campo = $request->otro_campo;

    //Compruebas que tengan algo los valores que envía el usuario:
    if(!empty($tipo_usuario)){
       $usuarios = $usuarios->where('tipo_id', $tipo_usuario);
    }

    if(!empty($otro_campo)){
       $usuarios = $usuarios->where('otro_campo', $otro_campo);
    }

    //Agregas los campos que te sean necesarios aquí...

    //Obtienes los resultados aquí:

    $usuarios = $usuarios->get(); //También puedes paginar los resultados pero es algo muy fácil de hacer y sugiero cheques la documentación

   //Para llenar el select del formulario, en el caso que tuvieras las opciones en base de datos:
   $tipos = TipoUsuario::get();

    return view('tabla-usuarios')->with(compact('usuarios', 'tipos'));
}
```

Y listo, tus parámetros serán agregados a la URL y tu controlador comprobará si existen.

Comment: Primero que nada, muchas gracias por tomarte la molestía de responderme, segundo, tu solución tiene buena pinta, excepto por un problema. Actualmente uso $usuarios = Usuario::latest()->paginate(10); ¿puede usar paginate() después del where?

Comment: @Carlos Si puedes, en vez de `$usuarios = $usuarios->get();` tendrías que hacer `$usuarios = $usuarios->paginate(10);`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, doy como solucionada mi pregunta :)

Comment: No puedo llevar esto a mis casos :(

Comment: @Carlos ¿por qué no?

Comment: ya está, tenía problemas para usar paginate() con distintos métodos.

Comment: Necesitaría que estos filtros hagan la petición sin necesidad de cliquear el botón "filtrar" ¿sabrías como se hace?

Comment: @Carlos Podrías adjuntar un evento `change` en los `select` o `input` que deseas, pero para este acercamiento yo creo que sería mejor que hicieras el filtrado por ajax.

Comment: ok, y el método al que debería llamar ajax sería index() o es mejor tener otra función para llenar las listas desplegables?